# Do I need to allocate memory for a pointer I didn't explicitly define?

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, memory, malloc

```
int main(){
    struct Map map;
    readInMap(&map);
    return 0;
}
void readInMap(struct Map * map){
   //do stuff
}
```

So when I send the map address over as a parameter am I risking some kind of memory allocation error? I couldn't find any question relating to this as I am lacking some vocabulary about what I'm doing. I've also looked into memallocation and would love a personal reference to something that explains it well in relation to pointers. I never learned that in class

Thank you

Edit: I was trying to figure out the most memory efficient way to perform the operations to the file I was going to perform. I was misusing pointers in c and found other threads with other relevant info to help me solve the problems I asked for like valgrind

Comment: You do not allocate memory for a pointer - you _have a pointer_. You allocate memory for an object _it points to_. Said that, now think for yourself: what is that object and where is it allocated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine. Function arguments are always copied, so original variable can remain unchanged. Basically in your function you will have local variable called `struct Map* map` which is pointer to an address. When you call it with `readInMap(&map);` you copy address of map to that local variable `struct Map* map` and that variable will exist only in `readInMap` function.

You are not risking any memory allocation error. You don't have to initialize anything because you only have one pointer and that's it.

As for code optimization, this is actually the best way of passing structure as argument, because you're copying only address, not whole structure. Let's look at another example:

```
typedef struct Node {

 char string[100];
 int variable1;
 int array[50];
} node;
```

If you  declare your function with `void readInMap(node map)`, when you actually call this function from main (as function argument you give structure variable, not pointer to structure), what will happen in function readInMap? As I said before, what happens behind scienes is this: Function will create it's own `node map` variable and copy all the values from argument you passed to that local variable. So in this structure I wrote, it will have to copy arrays and variables, and that is not optimized at all.

So you can solve this problem simply by declaring function with `void readInMap(struct Map * map)` like you did. Now only the address gets copied, not the whole structure and that is the best optimization when you use structures.

Comment: Thank you this answered my question perfectly

Answer (score 3):

That's fine, you're passing the address of map (which you created on the stack) to the `readInMap` function.

The `struct Map map;` line is allocating the memory for you (on the stack), so you have a valid `struct` to take the address of.

Comment: By using this method and keeping all functions in one file that would possibly need it am I being the most efficient? I want to optimize my program that creates, reads in, and finds a path through a maze all in one file

Comment: Efficiency has little to do with how many source files you have. Focus first on getting a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

You pass the address of a variable automatically allocated in the stack. You do not risk errors memory by doing that.

Comment: The OP's code allocates memory. It does so on the stack by defining `struct Map map`. How would this answer the OP's question.

Comment: I've heard enough about the two that this really helped my broader understanding of things. Thank you!

Comment: In my understanding when someone talk about memory allocation it means he does it "manually" (using malloc). The OP also said he lacks of vocabulary that why i pointed out the heap/stack question.

Comment: What about `alloca` then, @SebSaletes?  That would count as "manual" by your definition, but is never on the heap.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer Thank you to point this out to me! I never had to use this feature. Should I delete or edit my answer?

Comment: I'd edit it for sure.  As @alk points out, allocation is definitely happening.  I would also suggest that you identify relevant content from the links and include it (along with why it's relevant) or this becomes a "link only" answer.